# Why did NOT my Linux act the lazy memory allocation?

Tags: linux, mmap, lazy-initialization, numa, demand-paging

I'm practising to use the Lazy Allocation and the Demand Paging policies of Linux.

I want a buffer that I allocated by `mmap()` occupy **NO** physical memory until I really write something to it.
Further more, I want it gradually enlarge (use more physical memory) with a step size of the swap page size (e.g. 4K) of Linux along with I'm writing continuously from its head to the tail.

According to some [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/numa_memory_policy.html) and [searchings](https://offlinemark.com/2020/10/14/demand-paging/), it should **NOT** enlarge if there be only **reading** access on it, but the reality I observed in a experiment does NOT like this.

To test this, I coded a program as following, and watched the memory status by `top` shell command when it running.

```
constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    auto shm_pt = mmap( NULL, BUF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 );
    if( shm_pt == MAP_FAILED ) {
        std::cerr << "mmap error:" << shm_pt;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    };

    bool full_zero = true;
    uint8_t* pc = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>( shm_pt );

    constexpr size_t STEP_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
    for( size_t j = 0; j < BUF_SIZE / STEP_SIZE; ++j ) {
        this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );
        size_t base = j * STEP_SIZE;
        std::cerr << "Reading from " << base / 1024 / 1024 << "M..." << endl;

        for( size_t i = 0; i < STEP_SIZE; ++i )
            full_zero = full_zero && pc[ base + i ] == 0;
    }

    if( !full_zero )
        std::cerr << "The buffer has not been initialized with full zeros!";

    for( size_t j = 0; j < BUF_SIZE / STEP_SIZE; ++j ) {
        this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );
        size_t base = j * STEP_SIZE;
        std::cerr << "Writing to " << base / 1024 / 1024 << "M..." << endl;

        for( size_t i = 0; i < STEP_SIZE; ++i )
            pc[ base + i ] = 'c';
    }

    munmap( shm_pt, BUF_SIZE );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

What I observed is that the physical memory used by my app is growing gradually along with the **Reading** operation not with Writing op!

Perhaps my comprehension is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a link to one of the docs that led you to believe this?  It doesn't sound plausible to me.

Comment: Including what `top` is actually saying might be useful.

Comment: @MarkRansom https://offlinemark.com/2020/10/14/demand-paging/

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont When I watching by top cmd, and sort proccesses by RES usage, you will see the RES used by my app is increasing gradually along with reading.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

In the [searching content](https://offlinemark.com/2020/10/14/demand-paging/) I pasted, that man used a `MAP_PRIVATE` flag to `mmap()` as argument, while I used `MAP_SHARED`.

It looks like that if a buffer is being shared between processes, a READING operation also results real memory allocation!